# Early 2000s fantasy with colored stones of power

Tags: story-identification, books

I'm trying to find the title of a book for a patron who has been searching for this book for about 10 years. I believe it's about a middle grade book that she read in the early 2000's and she thought that it was new at the time. Here are the things she remembers:

-There are 5 or 6 stones of power. This particular book is about the red one. (Which might have strength powers but not sure)

-There is a squire with a pet falcon who wants to go on adventures

-There is a gypsy girl that is magical. Her mother is killed and she is searching for her missing brother. Her brother ends up being the assassin that is trying to kill the main characters.

-There is also a boy from our world that fell through a fountain on a school field trip into the magical world while reaching for the red stone.

It is not:

- The Deltora Quest
- EA Cycle
- The Seventh Tower series
- Diadem
- Westria
- Sword of Heavens -Worldstone (Stone Duology)

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting button as per the [tour].

Comment: Good details, by the way. The mention of the fountain struck a chord in me, and I then clicked into the first related item, expecting to use that new tab to start a search, only to find it was one of the cases where this has been answered. And above that was linked my own time when I'd answered it.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots I remembered something like this from searching for questions relating to gypsies, so I searched for `red stone gypsy` and found a different question with this as the answer.  So it's come up here at least 3 times now.

Answer (score 7):

This is probably *[Circle of Three](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2104152.Circle_of_Three)*, first book of the *Tales of the Nine Charms* series by Erica Farber as per [Book series - Boy finds gem and is transported to a fantasy world](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/217335/book-series-boy-finds-gem-and-is-transported-to-a-fantasy-world?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[image: Book cover for *Circle of Three*, with gems set along the side]

> Walker, ever the class clown, reaches into a fountain and finds the joke's on him when he wakes up in a distant world.
>
> Niko wants to be a warrior, but his master insists he learn the ways of a philosopher. What's the good of that?
>
> Aurora can do simple gypsy magic tricks, but even she doesn't know the true depths of her power.
>
> Drawn together by forces they don't understand, to combat an evil they can't imagine, their only weapons are nine simple charms.

Comment: Circle of Three is the book. Thank you!

Comment: @AbbiK: As per my other comment, you can officially accept an answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons. But thank you for your verbal acceptance. I have marked this question as a duplicate of a prior one. That is not a censure on you, but more a matter of bookkeeping on the site. Welcome!