# Fantasy kids' book about a medieval land with monsters and magical jewels

Tags: story-identification, books, medieval

A fantasy kids' book that was written as a collection of tales (like a fairytale anthology) about the same kingdom, set in medieval times. There is no set protagonist or plot line, it just all happens to take place in the same kingdom. There were some gems that had powers (there was an opal, a yellow gem, a purple gem, etc.) and there were monsters, specifically  dragons and wyverns.

The copy I had was a hardback that was decorated with plastic gems set into the typeface. There were pages of art that were really cool. The title might've been "Tales of the ———" (?).

I read it in sometime between 2013-2018 but I think it was published before 2010?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this, and when do you think it might've been published?

Comment: [Tales of the Kingdom](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1006442.Tales_of_the_Kingdom)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The book was [*Tales of Deltora*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tales_of_Deltora), a prequel book in the [Deltora Quest](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3100159-deltora-quest) series by Emily Rodda, as mentioned in [niko's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/267979/20774)

> [This book] is a chronicle of ancient stories from the Deltora Quest universe including how the evil Shadow Lord came to be, and how the great Adin obtained the seven gems from each of the tribes to form the Belt of Deltora.
>
> [image]

Comment: This was more of a comment than an answer, but since you've mentioned *which* book in the series was the correct one, I've bulked it out to a proper answer for you.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe [Deltora Quest](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3100159-deltora-quest) by Emily Rodda?

I actually ended up here because I was trying to find the name of this series. The one I had was a thick compilation of all the books, with the gemstones down the spine

All the books do follow the same overarching plot including various beasts and also the magical gems.

> Their quest is to find the seven gems of the fabled Belt of Deltora: the topaz, the ruby, the opal, the lapis lazuli, the emerald, the amethyst, and the diamond. The gems each have a special power and are hidden in dangerous locations around Deltora. The three friends must face numerous perils to reach them. Once the Belt is complete and the proper descendant of the first King of Deltora, Adin, wears the belt, the evil tyranny of the Shadow Lord will be forced back to the Shadowlands.

Comment: Holy cow yes this is it I love you I was looking for this for YEARS I was literally about to find my elementary school librarian to ask and HERE YOU ARE I read the secrets of Deltora which is the one about doran the dragon slayer which is why I didn’t know it actually even had a plot I just thought it was cool

Answer (score 1):

As per [An old book series about stones, teenagers, and parallel worlds](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/80731/an-old-book-series-about-stones-teenagers-and-parallel-worlds), might this be the *[Tales of the Nine Charms](https://www.goodreads.com/series/105154-tales-of-the-nine-charms)* series by Erica Farber, first book is *[Circle of Three](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2104152.Circle_of_Three)*?

[image: Book cover for Circle of Three, with gems set along the side]

> Walker, ever the class clown, reaches into a fountain and finds the joke's on him when he wakes up in a distant world.
>
> Niko wants to be a warrior, but his master insists he learn the ways of a philosopher. What's the good of that?
>
> Aurora can do simple gypsy magic tricks, but even she doesn't know the true depths of her power.
>
> Drawn together by forces they don't understand, to combat an evil they can't imagine, their only weapons are nine simple charms.

There's the cover with plastic gems set in it, a medieval setting, and magical jewels.

Comment: ah I don’t think so? The book I’m referring didn’t seem to have a cohesive plot and just seemed like a collection of stories like a fairytale book

Answer (score 1):

Is it [The Jewel Kingdom series](https://www.goodreads.com/series/69110-jewel-kingdom) by Jahnna N. Malcolm?

Summary from the first book, *[The Ruby Princess Runs Away](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/921533.The_Ruby_Princess_Runs_Away)*:

> Meet Roxanne, Sabrina, Emily, and Demetra, young sisters and princesses of the Jewel Kingdom. Each character has her own signature jewel and a special power. In the first book of the series, Roxanne must learn about leadership before she can be crowned with her ruby tiara. Free ruby necklace included.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could improve this answer by editing it to explain why you think this might be the correct book, i.e. the ways in which it matches the one described in the question. It'd help the rest of us to decide how likely this answer is to be correct, and whether we should therefore upvote it or not.

Comment: I added a quick blurb from Goodreads from the first book.